# linux g++ compiler redirect stderr and stdout creates empty file

Tags: linux, shell, g++

I am redirecting the g++ compiler output(both stderr and stdout) to a file on linux. But it is creating an empty file.

I read in some other post that stdout is not flushed after every line. Thats ok, but what about stderr. In my case there are compilation errors running several screens. So, I am interested in stderr output. There is no stdout output created.

```
 g++ -c -I ~/cplusplus/boost_1_37_0/boost_1_37_0/ -I 
~/cplusplus/niVxWorksDeliver/TEES/ Algorithms.cpp 2> output
```

The above command creates an empty file named "output". The following command reports invalid null command.

```
 g++ -c -I ~/cplusplus/boost_1_37_0/boost_1_37_0/ -I    
~/cplusplus/niVxWorksDeliver/TEES/ Algorithms.cpp &> output
Invalid null command.
```

Comment: What shell are you using? And is output generated when you don't do the redirection?

Comment: i am using putty to connect to a linux box which uses a bash shell

The main reason for redirection is to see the compilation errors which run across several screens.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One of your comments betrays that you are not using bash. You're using csh or tcsh. In that case, you can redirect all output (including standard error) like this:

```
g++ -c Algorithms.cpp >& output
```

For more csh redirection syntax, I have [a useful link](http://tomecat.com/jeffy/tttt/cshredir.html) bookmarked. Note that csh redirection syntax is not as fluent as bash syntax. You can do more in bash than you can in csh.

Comment: i am sorry for misleading you. That was only due to my ignorance. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm using `bash` and this syntax is still necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You might try this:

sh/bash/zsh version:

```
g++ -c -I ~/cplusplus/boost_1_37_0/boost_1_37_0/ \
       -I ~/cplusplus/niVxWorksDeliver/TEES/ \
       Algorithms.cpp > output 2>&1
```

csh or tcsh version:

```
g++ -c -I ~/cplusplus/boost_1_37_0/boost_1_37_0/ \
       -I ~/cplusplus/niVxWorksDeliver/TEES/ \
       Algorithms.cpp >& output
```

Comment: g++ -c -I ~/cplusplus/boost_1_37_0/boost_1_37_0/ -I ~/cplusplus/niVxWorksDeliver/TEES/ Algorithms.cpp > output 2>&1
Ambiguous output redirect.

Answer (score 0):

"No news is good news" -- does your command even produce any output? When there are no errors, g++ won't print out anything!

Comment: i am concerned about stderr. i know that compilation of a file doesnt produce any output :)